# SQLAlchemy Core : Combine three columns to act like one

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I am using SQLAlchemy core and the current specific application (dask.dataframe.read_sql_table), I need to feed it a singular column/selectable as an index field. One of the tables I am selecting from is large, but has only one unique key, which is a composite key.

DDL for the columns involved are:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `TABLENAME` (
  `FIRST_ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `SECOND_ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `OTHER_ID` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`FIRST_ID`,`SECOND_ID`,`OTHER_ID`),
  KEY `FK_NAST_SECOND_ID` (`SECOND_ID`),
  KEY `FIRST_ID_index` (`FIRST_ID`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

The plan that I have is if I can mimic a string column, and have logic that takes a string input in a specific pattern `FIRST_ID-SECOND_ID-OTHER_ID` and splits it into three columns and emits the values for each column so that instead of MySQL getting a where statement that is:

```
SELECT * from TABLENAME where CONCAT(FIRST_ID,'-',SECOND_ID,'-',OTHER_ID) = "1234-12-0"
```

(I don't think that is valid even, but it gets the idea across)

Instead MySQL gets:

```
SELECT * from TABLENAME where FIRST_ID = 1234 and SECOND_ID = 12 and OTHER_ID = 0;
```

The actual logic I can hammer out myself, just knowing how I can wrap the logic up inside some kind of fake column construct is the main issue.

Since this table has no single column unique keys, this is the best idea I came up with, so if there is a better way to represent that in SQLAlchemy Core for Dask to use, then I am all ears!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I was overcomplicating this. Pandas and Dask don't mind duplicate items in an index, so this was unnecessary. For an entire table dump, I only need to provide the table name and the column name if it is a numeric, indexed column. If it is something else you may need to define divisions or the like, but otherwise you can let Dask do its thing, and it is amazing.